# How to migrate Bower to NPM or Yarn for .Net Core 2.0 MVC project

Tags: npm, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bower

My project is .NET Core MVC where I have used Bower to manage Bootstrap, jQuery etc. Now Bower is going away, how I can migrate them to NPM or Yarn/Webpack as suggested by Bower?

Comment: Through the console like you'd do with any other usage. The problem is only with Visual Studio's tooling which hasn't been updated, yet, to use a different package manager. In other words, for now, you just have to forgo the fancy GUI.

Comment: @ChrisPratt : what do you mean by Through the console like you'd do with any other usage?

Comment: Use the CLI tools according to the documentation of whatever manager you choose. The point is that there's nothing in Visual Studio currently to help you. At least not natively. There may be an extension in the marketplace, so you can check that out too. However, ASP.NET Core is setup such that you technically don't even need VS. You can manage it like you would any old folder of files.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after few research, I kind of find a way that worked out for me. Here are my steps

Install gulp  thru NPM (add below entries in package.json)

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
   "gulp-uglify": "3.0.0",
   "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
   "gulp-cssmin": "0.2.0",
   "rimraf": "2.6.2",
 "lodash": "4.17.4",
```

Then also add other package dev dependencies (as we need to move away from bower). something like

```
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-validation": "1.17.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
     "fontawesome": "4.7.2"
```

Now NPM will download all packages to node_modules under the project root folder - you can see them by navigating to the windows folder browser or by opting for show all files in VS

Now next step is set up tasks in gulp task runner. For that add gulpfile.js from add new item directly under web project. Once file added we havce to define gulp taks that will run at build.

Bellow is a sample file that does 3 task - copy packages from node-modules to wwwroot/lib/_app and clean/minify css and js file. And all tasks been configured to run as build process which is manged under VS task runner

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='clean, clean:css, clean:js, min, min:css, min:js, copy-assets' Clean='clean, min:js, clean:css, copy-assets' />
"use strict";

var _ = require('lodash'),
    gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};
gulp.task('copy-assets', function () {
    var assets = {
        js: [
            './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
            './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            './node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js',
           './node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js'


        ],
        css: ['./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css']
    };
    _(assets).forEach(function (assets, type) {
        gulp.src(assets).pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/lib/_app/" + type));
    });
});
//gulp.task("copy-assets");



paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

This works fine when working locally on VS. But we need to configure csproj show that it can be worked during VSTS build process. This will be done by adding below config in web .csproj

```
<Target Name="buildName" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="gulp clean" />
    <Exec Command="gulp copy-assets" />
    <Exec Command="gulp min" />
    </Target>
```

Now all good - during build all necessary packages will be copied under wwwroot/lib/_app and you can point your css/js ref to there such as below in _Layout.cshtml

```
<link href="~/lib/_app/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the steps outlined in this article and it worked perfectly https://itnext.io/bower-to-yarn-migration-simple-steps-2a5ad0c43281

STEP 1 — Install yarn

npm i yarn -g

Install yarn globally using above command then verify installation by running yarn -v command.

STEP 2 — Install bower-away

npm i bower-away -g

We also need to install bower-away package globally and then navigate to your project directory and run following command

bower-away

this step will examine the bower.json and move the bower_components to package.json file and prepare it for user preview.

STEP 3 — Preview Changes

bower-away --diff

STEP 4 — Apply changes

bower-away --apply

Now apply changes using above command and then we need to delete bower_components folder from our project.

For Mac/Linux — rm -rf client\bower_components

For Windows — Remove-Item -Path .\client\bower_components\ -Force

STEP 5 — Install new modules

yarn

before you run the last yarn command:
One thing to mention that the article doesn't tell you, if using for .net MVC project create a .yarnrc file in the same directory as the package.json file , then add this to the .yarnrc file to have to install the packages to the wwwroot folder:

```
--modules-folder wwwroot/lib
```